# React Route overlap other page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

App.js

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={Login} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
```

Login.js

```
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="login-box">
        <div className="login-wrap">
            <form id="login-form" action="#" >
                <input type="text" placeholder="ID"/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="PWD"/>
                <Link to="/Edit">
                <button>Login</button>
                </Link>
                
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <Switch>
    <Route exact={true} path="/Edit" component={Edite}/>
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

I want to click login button, then go to Edit pages but this code is overlap components.
So I tryed it  add `<Switch>` tag`exact={true}` but always overlap components.
How can I solve the problem? (*Sorry I can't speak English well.)

Comment: Could you put this into something that could be run easily? Like in codesanbox or simply a Git repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `<Route>` and `<BrowserRouter>` in every jsx file. use those only inside the app.js and `<Link>` in other components.

In app.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
     return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        {/*if you have nevbar use it on here(out side the Switch)*/}
        <Route path="/" component={Nevbar} />
        
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/Edit" exact component={Edite}/>
        </Switch>

         {/*if you have footer use it on here(out side the Switch)*/}
         <Route path="/" component={Footer} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
  }
  
}
```

Inside the login.jsx

```
<Link to="/Edit"><button>Login</button> </Link>
```

is enough to navigate to the required component.

Comment: wow...really thank you!! I shouldn't have used```<BrowserRouter>``` in other js file...thx!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
    <Route exact={true} path="/Edit" component={Edite}/>
    <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Login} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

declare your routes in App.js. so when you declare it inside login then the already rendered login page will persist and the edit will be rendered below the login page. so if you declare it in App.js we are directing to go either to login page or edited page